# Create separate class for connection string

Tags: c#, winforms

i am trying to create separate class for connection named Connection.cs, why am i having this error while executing the query

`ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed`

what am i doing wrong ?

in my Dal.cs class

```
 public void Insert(string f1,string f2)
            {
                string query;
                Connection c = new Connection();
                c.OpenCnn();
                try  {
                    query = "inset into ..."
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

               catch (Exception ex){
                   throw ex;
                }

                finally {
                     c.CloseCnn();
                }
            }
```

and in my Connection.cs class

```
public class Connection

    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        public void OpenCnn()
        {
       string cnnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstrng"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(cnnStr);
            con.Open();
        }

        public void CloseCnn()
        {

            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting and when? Try debugging

Comment: Where did `con` come from in Insert method? Nothing is public in `Connection` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the con field is `private` and can not be accessible from outside of `Connection` class.

You can add a property to your connection class:

```
public SqlConnection Connection { get { return con; } }
```

Then access it via your instance:

```
 Connection c = new Connection();
 c.OpenCnn();
 try 
 {
      query = "inset into ..."
      cmd = new SqlCommand(query, c.Connection);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Btw, I'm not sure what are you referring by `con` in your `Insert` method (probably a local variable instead of the `con` field, because otherwise it wouldn't even compile)

Comment: thnx it worked  i was defining SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); in my insert method

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Connection
{       
    SqlConnection con;

    public SqlConnection Conn { get { return con; } }

    public void OpenCnn()
    {
        string cnnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstrng"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(cnnStr);
        con.Open();
    }

    public void CloseCnn()
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Method `Insert`:

Note `SqlCommand` initialization and usage of public property `conn`.

```
public void Insert(string f1, string f2)
{
    string query;
    Connection c = new Connection();
    c.OpenCnn();
    try  
    {
        query = "insert into ..."
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, c.Conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
               throw ex;
    }
    finally {
       c.CloseCnn();
    }
 }
```